# Not able to update user profile using DocuSign admin API [docusignapi]

Tags: c#, docusignapi, webapi

I want to update user profile (Federated_status) of user, I am using DocuSign admin APi and generated temporary token from organization admin account - but when I call the Docusing admin api using below it doesn't update it and throws error "unauthorized".

```
'''try
            {
                HttpContent PostContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjUser), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                string reponsebody = string.Empty;
                string Url = "https://api-d.docusign.net/managment/v2/organisation/" + OrgID + "users/profiles";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application / json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token));
                    HttpResponseMessage rep = client.PostAsync(new System.Uri(Url), PostContent).Result;
                    reponsebody = rep.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                var userProfileResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(reponsebody);
                return userProfileResponse;
            }



'''

I am not sure how to call this admin api to update user profile - "federated status" .
Please help.!
```

Comment: see Matt's answer below, but also, please explain exactly how you got the token, did you get consent? do you use JWT Auth? do you have a keypair?

Comment: I am using temporary access token generated.i am using Authorization code grant .

Comment: the scopes are specified in the URL that you call to generate the login UI using Auth Code Grant.

Comment: Thanks @inbar , I am getting error now error -  404 - method not found, the api method url I used is https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/(used orgid)/users/profiles

Comment: different question, but I'll answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
GET /v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users/profile
```

but the update is:

```
POST /v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users/profiles
```

Different endpoint, I know it's confusing.

Make sure you do a POST, not a GET

https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/reference/Users/Users/updateUser

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not including the proper scopes when obtaining your access token. For requests to DocuSign Admin API, you must include special scopes. I've included some code examples for each type of authentication.

If you're using JWT, your token body will look something like this...

```
{
  "iss": "5c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f",
  "sub": "464f7988-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-781ee556ab7a",
  "iat": 1523900289,
  "exp": 1523903289,
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "scope": "signature organization_read group_read user_read user_write"
}
```

For Auth Code Grant, your request must include the DocuSign Admin scopes, included in this sample:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20organization_read%20group_read%20user_read%20user_write&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/http://example.com/callback/
```

For Implicit grant, your request will be similar, except a different response type

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature%20organization_read%20group_read%20user_read%20user_write&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/
```

For more information on the various types of scope, see our guide on [DocuSign Admin API Auth](https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/guides/auth). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, I am using c# console application, I don't understand if I should use the JWT or auth code grant. Could you please suggest what should I use for c# console application

Comment: Sure thing. For system integrations, you'll want to follow the JWT flow. This will enable you to make DOCU API requests under a single account. For more info, check out this infographic - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @ Matthew - Now, I am getting error 404 - method not found, the api method url I used is https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/(used orgid)/users/profiles

Comment: I update code to user Auth Code Grant with scope as suggested above but still getting same error